# Routes work in Development But not in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Weird Error. I have some routes that work perfectly during development but once i deploy and try to access them it comes up with page does not Exist error

I have the following routes.rb file:

```
TransportUnl::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :trucks

  resources :shipments do
    collection do
      get :autocomplete_location_cs
    end
  end

  devise_for :users do
    get '/users/sign_in' => 'devise/sessions#new'
    get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end

  root :to => 'info#index'

  resources :info do
    collection do
      get 'about'
      get 'contact'
      get 'you_dont_have_a_full_account'
      get 'help'
    end
    member do
      get 'index'
    end
  end

  resources :companies

end
```

Not everything is setup yet. but i am getting a page not found error when i go to:

```
www.website.com/shipments

www.website.com/trucks
```

as well as others in production.  The main index page works and you can login but these pages come up not found.

### Production

[image: Production]

### Development

[image: Development]

Production.log

```
Started GET "/shipments" for 108.235.52.160 at 2015-06-22 13:09:03 -0500
Processing by ShipmentsController#index as HTML
  [1m[35m (0.6ms)[0m  SELECT MAX("shipments"."price") AS max_id FROM "shipments" 
  [1m[36mShipment Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "shipments".* FROM "shipments" [0m
  Rendered shipments/_nav.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered shipments/_search_table.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered shipments/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.2ms)
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.5ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (5.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"companies"}):
  app/views/shared/_header.html.erb:78:in `_app_views_shared__header_html_erb___2847381188393053217_232073740'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:17:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__4421904906041360553_230384600'
  app/controllers/shipments_controller.rb:7:in `index'




Started GET "/info/about" for 157.55.39.229 at 2015-06-22 13:10:29 -0500
Processing by InfoController#about as */*
  Rendered info/about.html.erb within layouts/application (5.7ms)
  Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (3.8ms)
  [1m[36m (4.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT * FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name='shipments'[0m
  [1m[35mShipment Load (0.9ms)[0m  SELECT "shipments".* FROM "shipments" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (31.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 177ms (Views: 151.1ms | ActiveRecord: 25.6ms)
```

the Link is created like this:

```
<%= link_to "My Account", edit_company_path(current_user.company_id) %>
```

Comment: what about production.log?

Comment: You can see in your `production.log` that the line 78 of `app/views/shared/_header.html.erb` is calling a wrong route (edit action of the companies controller without an id)

Comment: it should have the value of `current_user.company_id`

Comment: what if there is no current user ? did you handle this case too?

Comment: this is right after login....

Comment: i have fully incorporated cancan yet... but at that point it should have a user.

Comment: The header changes After a user is logged in... if no user is logged it you have a basic header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from logs, you got error page because of line 78 of `app/views/shared/_header.html.erb` file.

In this piece of code, where you creating link

```
<%= link_to "My Account", edit_company_path(current_user.company_id) %>
```

Check if company_id is not nil for that particular user. I'm pretty sure it's nil in your case.

As you can see from error logs, it tries to get action edit as collection action of companies controller - `companies/edit`. You don't have this route defined. But if current user will have company_id, the link will be built correctly and you wont receive an error.

Comment: Thanks... the company should have been made will have to look further into things thanks